# What is the colon ':' called in category theory morphism definitions?

Tags: category-theory, notation, morphism

Category theoretic morphism definition syntax, e.g.: $\varphi : G \to H$ uses the colon character rather than, for instance, the member-of sign e.g.: $\varphi ∈ G \to H$

What is the descriptive name of colon in this context? What is the semantic gain of this additional entity over member-of?

Comment: The function $\varphi$ does not "equal" $G \to H$ (whatever that means).  There are probably lots of functions/morphisms $G \to H$.  This notation says that $\varphi$ is one of them.

Comment: Roughly speaking, a colon can often be replaced with the phrase "such that". For instance, $\varphi:G\to H$ reads "$\varphi$ such that $G$ maps to $H$".

Comment: @Shaun: People do occasionally use $:$ to mean 'such that', for example in set-builder notation (e.g. $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \ge 0 \}$) or after an existential quantifier (e.g. $\exists x \in \mathbb{R} : x \ge 0$), but in the context of a function (or morphism in a category) that is neither what the colon means nor how it is read.

Comment: I've never heard anyone read this colon as "such that."

Answer (score 5):

The colon is a typing symbol and does not represent equality.

The assertion $\varphi : G \to H$ asserts that $\varphi$ is a morphism from the object $G$ to the object $H$. There may be many different morphisms from $G$ to $H$, so replacing $:$ by $=$ would not make much sense.

There are instances when a morphism is understood from context, when you might write an $=$ sign. For example, if you see something like:

> ...*blah blah blah*... and so we see trivially that $f = A \to 1$.

What is probably meant is that $1$ is a terminal object in a category $\mathcal{C}$ and $f$ is the unique morphism from $A$ to $1$ in $\mathcal{C}$.

Related note: in the branch of [type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory), the colon is used more widely; the notation $a : A$ represents the assertion that a term $a$ has type $A$. In type theory, the notation $A \to B$ represents a *function type*, and then a function $f : A \to B$ truly is a term $f$ of type $A \to B$.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that with set-theoretic foundations, the notation $f:A\to B$ would typically be viewed as shorthand for $f\in\mathsf{Hom}(A,B)$. The OP's question would have made a lot more sense if they'd contrasted to $\in$ rather than $=$. There's probably a decent and not completely superficial discussion on why type theory uses $:$ over $\in$ that could be had, but that's another question...

Comment: @DerekElkins: Good point. (For what it's worth, I have seen some presentations of type theory that use $\in$ instead of $:$.)

Comment: I've corrected my question to use ∈ as the counter-example.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

> The colon “:” generally *abbreviates* a pair of equalities.

A category is generally defined as consisting of things called ‘objects’ and
‘morphisms’ --as well as other things--
such that:
*Each morphism $f$ has an associated “source” object and an associated “target” object.*

To avoid being verbose, a syntactic construct is introduced:
$$
f : A → B \qquad≡\qquad \mathsf{source}\,f \,=\, A \;\;\land\;\; \mathsf{target}\,f \,=\, B
$$

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: This is extremely pedantic but technically simply knowing that $\mathsf{source}(f)=A$ and $\mathsf{target}(f)=B$ does not ensure that $f$ is a morphism of the category. You'd need an additional constraint like $f\in\mathsf{Arr}(\mathcal C)$.

Comment: I've corrected my question to use ∈ as the counter example.  The syntactic sugar approach appeals to me but it leaves me a bit dissatisfied as it doesn't suggest a nice verbal translation e.g. "f morphs the category A to the category B" or something like that.

Comment: $\mathsf{source,target}$ are usual set-functions from the arrows of a category to its objects...